# In cakephp 2.x How to get third table data using join table?

Tags: cakephp, associations, join

```
'books
    id,name
categories
    id,name
books_categories
    id,book_id,category_id'
```

' App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
    class Book extends AppModel {

```
    public $useTable = 'books';
    public $belongsTo = array(

        'Agerange' => array(
            'className' => 'Agerange',
            'foreignKey' => 'agerange_id'
        ),
        'Publication' => array(
            'className' => 'Publication',
            'foreignKey' => 'publication_id'
        ),
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Book_Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'book_id',
            'joinTable' => 'books_categories',
            'fields' => array('Category_id',),          
        )
    );
}

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Book_Category extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'books_categories';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Book' => array(
            'className' => 'Book',
            'foreignKey' => 'book_id'
        ),
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
        )
    );


}

in BooksController ......

$this->paginate = array(
            'contains'=>array('Book','Publication','Agerange','Book_Category'),            
            'order' => 'Book.id ASC');

            $books = $this->paginate('Book');

    enter code here


{
Book: {id: "111", title: "ABC", subtitle: "English Today Primer", author: "Pruthviraj",…},…}
Agerange:{id: "31", from: "0", to: "2", status: true}
Book:{id: "111", title: "ABC", subtitle: "English Today Primer", author: "Pruthviraj",…}
Category:[{Category_id: "5", book_id: "111"}]
}'
```

**Output** Now I am getting only category_id:5 it's okay but I want name field also of category so How can I get name field of category using Book and Book_Category?

Comment: Try adding $this->Model->recursive = 2 before executing the query on table. Which automatically gets corresponding data as per the belongsTo or w/e conditions you setup on model

Answer (score 0):

Modify your contain array by adding `Categoy` to `Book_Category`

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'contains' => array(
        'Book',
        'Publication',
        'Agerange',
        'Book_Category' => 'Category'
    ),
    'order' => 'Book.id ASC'
);
```

OR Use hasAndBelongsToMany association, it's much simpler

Start by deleting the `Book_Category`

Then change the book Model

```
class Book extends AppModel {

public $useTable = 'books';

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Agerange' => array(
        'className' => 'Agerange',
        'foreignKey' => 'agerange_id'
    ),
    'Publication' => array(
        'className' => 'Publication',
        'foreignKey' => 'publication_id'
    ),
);

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'joinTable' => 'books_categories',
        'foreignKey' => 'book_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id'
    )
);
```

}

Then, in your controller change the pagination setting like this

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'contains' => array(
        'Publication',
        'Agerange',
        'Category'  
    ),
    'order' => 'Book.id ASC'
);
```

@link [Cakephp HABTM association](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)